# How to make non-blocking raw_input when using eventlet.monkey_patch() and why it block everything, even when executed on another thread?

Tags: python, nonblocking, raw-input, eventlet

I wrote this minimum code to explain my case:

```
import threading
import time
import eventlet

eventlet.monkey_patch()

def printing_function():
    while True:
        # here i want to do some work
        print "printing"
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=printing_function)
    thread.start()

    while True:
        # here i want to wait for users input
        raw_input("raw input\n")
        print "inside main loop"
        time.sleep(1)
```

Even i have 2 threads, both of them are blocked when i call raw_input. When i comment out eventlet.monkey_patch(), only one thread is blocked and another keep printing "printing". Why and what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that there are a couple of things to note here:

- `raw_input` isn't patched by `eventlet`, so its calls are blocking
- `threading` is patched by `eventlet`, so threads are acting as coroutines

One way to workaround this would be to avoid patching `threading`, so that threads are real threads. To do that, you just need to replace:

```
eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

with:

```
eventlet.monkey_patch(os=True,
                     select=True,
                     socket=True,
                     thread=False,
                     time=True)
```

Note that when `thread` is `True` the following modules are patched: `thread`, `threading`, `Queue`.

Edit: If you want to patch `threading` and have an asynchronous `raw_input`, then I suggest the following implementation:

```
def raw_input(message):
    sys.stdout.write(message)

    select.select([sys.stdin], [], [])
    return sys.stdin.readline()
```

This will poll `sys.stdin` to check if it's ready for reading. If that's not the case, it will yield control to eventlet to let other coroutine execute.

Comment: So if i need to patch threads (thread, threading and Queue) making non-blocking raw_input is not possible?

Comment: @SuitUp I think it would be easier to have one separate thread to handler user iput. However, if you want to use only coroutines, I've added an example implementation that will work on unix systems.

Comment: So i should just import thread before monkey_patching everyting? Make this separate thread handle user input and let other things be coroutines, right? Thank you for help.

Comment: @SuitUp Any code after `monkey_patch` will use the patched module regardless of when the import happened. For further granularity, you can use `threading` and `eventlet.green.threading` instead of monkey patching.

Comment: @SuitUp Alternatively, I've seen that `monkey_patch` patches `select.select` which makes the custom `raw_input` easier to implement since there's no longer need to poll in a loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, now, how can i vote up you even more? ;)

Comment: +1 @jcollado    for the custom raw_input workaround. I was getting ready to learn about GIL and use `sys.setcheckinterval()` but a final try brought me here. If anyone else wants to implement: no need for `eventlet`, just `import select` and use `def raw_input(message):` above. raw_input will no longer block your threads and no need for ncurses!