# gevent.StreamServer and non-blocking raw_input()?

Tags: python, gevent

I've written a simple tcp server using `gevent.StreamServer` for testing purposes. In order for me to send responses to some of the clients, I need a non-blocking way to handle input via `raw_input()`, preferrably without using threads.

After some googling I stumbled across this question: [How to make non-blocking raw_input when using eventlet.monkey_patch() and why it block everything, even when executed on another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027311/how-to-make-non-blocking-raw-input-when-using-eventlet-monkey-patch-and-why-it)

I've written the following and it does exactly what I want however I assume there's better approach to it. Could someone point me to the right direction? Also, an idea why the try/except does not catch the KeyboardInterrupt is appreciated.

```
import select
from gevent.monkey import patch_all
from gevent.server import StreamServer

patch_all(os=True, select=True)

def raw_input(message):
    """ Non-blocking input from stdin. """
    sys.stdout.write(message)

    select.select([sys.stdin], [], [])
    return sys.stdin.readline()

def main():
    """ Run the server, listen for commands """

    server = StreamServer(("0.0.0.0", 6000), handle)
    print "Starting server"
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, server.close)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, server.close)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGINT, server.close)

    server.start()
    while True:
        try:
            a = raw_input("")
            if a:
                print "Received %s" % a
            gevent.sleep(0)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "Received a shutdown signal, going down ..."
            server.stop()
            sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

EDIT: I've rewritten parts of the code and I now understand the silliness of the main()-function. I'll post it as an edit in case someone stumbles on this question and has a better idea on how to do it.

```
from gevent.signal import signal

def get_console_input():
    """ Non-blocking console input to the server """

    select.select([sys.stdin], [], [])
    # There's quite a bit of code here but it is input handling so 
    # for shortness's sake   I've snipped everything and return the line read.
    return sys.stdin.readline()

def exit(server):
    """ Quit the server gracefully """

    print "Received shutdown signal, going down. """
    server.close()
    sys.exit(0)

def main():
    """ The main function. Create and run the server, listen for commands and
   append any command to the server so it can send them on to the clients """

    # Myserver is a class which inherits from gevent.server.StreamServer.
    # Myserver could just as well be replaced by gevent.server.StreamServer.

    server = MyServer(("0.0.0.0", PORT))
    print "Starting server"

    # Add some signal handlers to quit the server gracefully.
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit, server)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, exit, server)
    gevent.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit, server)

    # Server started in async mode
    server.start()

    while True:
        get_console_input()
        gevent.sleep(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way I've found to do this is to use [`gevent.socket.wait_read`](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.socket.html#gevent.socket.wait_read) to wait until `sys.stdin` can be read:

```
wait_read(sys.stdin.fileno())
return sys.stdin.readline()
```

I've also written a small wrapper around file descriptors to give them non-blocking `.read()` and `.write()` methods: https://gist.github.com/2915875

Comment: Thanks, seems to be quite what I'm looking for!

Comment: Works well in OSX, but doesn't seem to work properly in Windows.  The wait_read raises "IOError: [Errno 0] No error"

Comment: as of now gevent doesn't have wait_read and wait_write method