# python 3 - gevent threads not running in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, concurrency, gevent

I'm trying to use the gevent greenlets to create some long running threads, like workers, but I've a problem when asking input to the user, ex:

```
import gevent
import time

from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()


def func():
    while True:
        print('working')
        time.sleep(2)


def func2():
    while True:
        print(input('input: '))


gevent.joinall([
    gevent.spawn(func),
    gevent.spawn(func2)
])
```

This will run once func, and then will wait for user input, but stops to print `working`.

Tried also to wait input on the main thread:

```
from gevent import Greenlet
import time

from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()


def func():
    while True:
        print('working')
        time.sleep(2)


g = Greenlet(func)
g.start()

while True:
        print(input('input: '))
```

But there the greenlet is not starting. Where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in python3 input not got patched to “green” version, so it wont give up execution to switch to other greenlet see [doc](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html)

Comment: How can I get input without locking everything?

Comment: why use builtin thread is not an option for you?

Comment: Because i'm already using gevent with the wsgiserver, and i need a way to run it in background and also do some other background tasks

Comment: this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601382/gevent-streamserver-and-non-blocking-raw-input

Answer (score 0):

You need to know about the concept of coroutine.

When `func` executes `time.sleep(2)`. As `time.sleep` is patched by gevent. It's not just hanging there for 2 seconds. It is also giving the control to the event loop.

In the event loop, the next registered coroutine is `func2`, so it starts executing `func2`

The reason why it never print "working" again is because the code in `func2` is "blocking", which means it never giving the control back to the event loop.

In order to make these coroutine executing cooperatively (`func` -> `func2` -> `func` -> ...).

You must put something that can give the control back to the event loop.

For example, change `func2` to this will work:

```py
def func2():
    while True:
        print(input('input: '))
        time.sleep(0.1)
```